Why does the ls command output in Windows Terminal running Ubunt start with a ''$'\001''?' string in WSL2 using zsh?
I get an encoding issue with the ls command as seen here:

When I change ~/.zshrc to have a LC_ALL in UTF8 encoding, the output changes to \001\357\277\275. What do I need to do to fix this?

It turns out that it was some sort of empty file. I deleted it by pressing tab after rm and everything looks good now! I thought that something was broken--I'm not sure where it came from.

There are exactly two characters that can't be put in a unix filename.

@user10489 do you have any idea where it came from? Is there a way that I could find out?

Most likely, fat fingered something.   If you hadn't deleted it, you could check the date and see when it happened.  If you're lucky, it might still be in your history, otherwise a mystery forever.  We've all done it at some time probably.
